# UINavigationItem touchView touch size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm setting a view on my UINavigationItem's touchView and adding a tap gesture recognizer to it.  What's weird, is that the tap recognizer is getting called even when the tap is outside of the view.  Any idea why this might be happening?

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 120.0f, 20.0f)];
testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:)];
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
[testView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
testView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.navigationItem.titleView = testView;
```

I can click outside the red box and still trigger the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score -1):

use this way

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(doStuff:)];
```

instead of this code

```
 UIGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:)];
```

Comment: Still essentially the same thing.